# The relationship between Firmata, Arduino and Node js

Tags: node.js, arduino, firmata, johnny-five

This is a basic question of understanding. I'm trying to follow this explanation http://www.barryvandam.com/node-js-communicating-with-arduino/ but something there sounds a bit off to me.

As far as I understood before, I only need to push the standard Firmata code into the Arduino and code via Node.js to call actions and information from the Arduino. 
But in this link they point our that I need to upload a code to the Arduino, which will obviously delete the Firmata code that is now there. wouldn't it result in loosing connection to the Arduino?

How does it work?

many thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Firmata is one way to communicate with an Arduino, you do not have to use it.

You can "talk" to Arduindo directly using the SerialPort module - which is what the linked example is doing.

Comment: yeah but do i have to use firmata to communicate to node.js? or is there a way to communicate SerialPort to Node.js, without firmata?

Comment: You do not have to use firmata. The linked example does not use firmata.

Answer (score 5):

The example above does not use Firmata, though Firmata makes things easier.  If you want to implement your own serial control protocol, there nothing stopping you.

However, if you load StandardFirmata on your Arduino, and then use the [Firmata.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firmata) package in node, then you have a full-featured, well established serial protocol and an api to access the pins from.

There are Firmata controller implementations for most languages out there.

On top of Firmata.js, you might choose to use an abstraction called [Johnny-Five](http://johnny-five.io/).  Johnny-Five abstracts the pins as components, with an intuitive API.  Instead of controlling a servo by setting a pin value, you create a servo, and call `servo.to(angle)`.  It is kind of like jQuery but for hardware.  It abstracts the platforms and devices in such a way that the shape of the interface is the same, but the hardware might be completely different.  It is a very comfortable place to develop from.

Answer (score 0):

Firmata is a set of functions that you can pre-load onto your Arduino that libraries like Johnny-Five can call to perform certain tasks.

As previously said by the author of the accepted answer, you don't have to use it, you can write your own logic to send and receive custom message.

In Node.js you can use the [node-serialport](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport) library to send the message:

```
myPort.write();
```

Then read the message from the Arduino with the built in Serial library:

```
while(radio.available()){
    radio.read(chr, 1);
}
```